# Network Shares disappeared after adding shared volume to boot items

Tags: snow-leopard, network

I wanted to add a have a network share mount on boot so I added it to the users boot items. The volume mounted successfully but other network shares are no longer visible either through the sidebar or via Finder > Go > Network.

Previously my other mac book pro, which is set up for screen sharing would be in the server list as would my NAS (Lacie Network Space), which would appear as both an afp and smb share. The NAS is now the only option available as afp or smb, it was one of the shared folders on this that I added as a boot item.

Finder > Go > Connect to Server works but I no longer have the option to browse for shares

I have removed the share from the boot items.

So far I have tried:

- unchecking all options under Finder > Preferences > Sidebar > Shared, rebooting and then checking again.
- Deleting all the files in Library > Preferences > SystemConfiguration and rebooting
- Replacing all files in the above from a previous back up

Unfortunately I don't back up anywhere near enough so a full restore from back up is a last resort.

All shares are visible from my other macbook pro, running Leopard

The real question is how to I make the network shares visible/browsable again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this turns out not to be a Mac issue after all!

Restarting my router fixes the problem. It seems to have DNS issues every now and then.